# Elastic Search: should inside must for multiple or conditions, not working as expected

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-7

Let me explain my problem through the different cases I have.

With this query, with no filters applied, I receive results for both programs (each one belonging to each different index): `confess-chrome` && `http-down-burst-test`
[image: First case]

If I apply a *"should inside must"* boolean query, where I apply same restriction to each program, I also receive results for both programs, but as expected, the average now has a value of 1:
[image: Second case]

But, in the same last query, if I apply the restriction for only one of the programs (*confess-chrome*), then I don't receive results for the other program (*http-down-burst-test*):
[image: Third case]

If my separated restrictions by program are inside a should query, why I only receive results for one program and not the other?

How should I build my query in order to receive results for both *confess-chrome* (restricted with `globales.success=1`) and for *http-down-burst-tests* without any restrictions applied?

Comment: You should do like in your second query, but without the `globales.success: 1` restriction on `http-down-burst-test`

Comment: @Val that was easy ‍♂️  didn't know this behaviour, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You should do like in your second query, but without the `globales.success: 1` restriction on `http-down-burst-test`.

PS: You should share textual code instead of screenshots, as it's easier to copy/paste queries. Retyping everything manually is not a good time investment ;-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, and sorry for the inconvenience 